# $n$-wise extension of covariance / correlation

Tags: st.statistics

Suppose we have $n$ random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and we want some sort of characterization about how "statistically" related they are as a whole, with the motivation being that for $n=2$ we have metrics such as covariance and (Pearson) correlation.

We can express $n$-wise independence for example: we require the joint pdf $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to be the product of the marginals: $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)$. We can also build off the pair-wise case. For example, we can consider some matrix norm of the covariance matrix. Ideally, however, I would like some characterization of $n$-wise built in, like what we have for $n$-wise independence.

I would suspect that if some number $C(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ be assigned to this idea, then it would have to satisfy:

1. $C(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$ if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are $n$-wise independent (in the manner expressed above).
2. $C(x_i, \ldots, x_i) = \sigma^n_i$ for $\sigma_i = \operatorname{std}(X_i)$.
3. $C(x_1, x_j) = \operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j)$

among other conditions. Is this some well-defined concept?

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thank you and Michael Hardy for your very clarifying answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Var{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand\Cov{\operatorname{Cov}}$In conditions 1--3 in your post, the $x_i$'s are used improperly in place of the $X_i$'s. Also, the functions $C$ must of course be different for different numbers of their arguments.

After an appropriate cleaning, the question becomes as follows: for each integer $n\ge2$, propose a function $C_n$ of $n$ real arguments such that

1. $C_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)=0$ if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent random variables (r.v.'s) with finite second moments.
2. $C_n(\underbrace{X,\dots,X}_n)=(\Var X)^{n/2}$ if $X$ is a r.v. with a finite second moment.
3. $C_2(X_1,X_2)=\Cov(X_1,X_2)$ if $X_1,X_2$ are r.v.'s with finite second moments.

These conditions will hold if e.g.
$$C_n(X_1,\dots,X_n):=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n} \Cov(X_i,X_j)^{[1/(n-1)]}$$
for any r.v.'s $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with finite second moments, where $u^{[p]}:=|u|^p\,\text{sign}\, u$ for real $u$ and real $p>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you denote random variables by capital $X\text{s},$ you should stick with that, and probably reserve the lower-case $x$ for arguments to its p.d.f. and c.d.f. and the like.

There is the idea of the joint cumulant $\kappa$ of a tuple of random variables, characterized as exemplified here:

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(X_1\cdots X_5) & & \text{(expected value of the product)} \\[6pt]
= {} & \kappa(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5) & & \text{(joint cumulant of 5 random variables)} \\[6pt]
& +{} \underbrace{\kappa(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) \kappa(X_5) + \cdots\cdots}_{\binom 5 1 \text{terms}} \\[6pt]
& {} + {} \underbrace{ \kappa(X_1,X_2,X_3) \kappa(X_4,X_5) + \cdots\cdots}_{\binom52 \text{ terms}} \\[6pt]
& {} + {} \underbrace{\kappa(X_1,X_2,X_3)\kappa(X_4)\kappa(X_5) + \cdots\cdots}_{\binom52 \text{terms}} \\[6pt]
& {} + {} \underbrace{\kappa(X_1,X_2)\kappa(X_3,X_4) \kappa(X_5) + \cdots\cdots}_\text{15 terms} \\[6pt]
& {} + {} \underbrace{\kappa(X_1,X_2)\kappa(X_3)\kappa(X_4) \kappa(X_5) + \cdots\cdots}_{\binom 5 2\text{ terms}} \\[6pt]
& {} + {} \kappa(X_1) \kappa(X_2) \kappa(X_3) \kappa(X_4) \kappa(X_5)
\end{align}
and similarly for other cardinalities than $5.$ Above you have all $52$ partitions of a set of $5$ members; similarly for the joint cumulant of six random variables you have $203$ terms, etc.

Hence the cumulant of one random variable is the expected value, the cumulant of two random variables is the covariance, and the identity above determines the way in which other joint cumulants depend on the expected values of products.

If all of the random variables are the same, we have something like this:
$$
\kappa_5(X) = \kappa(X,X,X,X,X),
$$
which satisfies
\begin{align}
\operatorname E(X^5) = {} & \kappa_5(X) + 5\kappa_4(X)\kappa_1(X) + 10\kappa_3(X)\kappa_2(X) \\[6pt]
& {} + 10 \kappa_3(X) \kappa_1(X)^2 + 15\kappa_2(X)^2\kappa_1(X) \\[6pt]
& {} + 10\kappa_2(X)\kappa_1(X)^3 + \kappa_1(X)^5.
\end{align}

The simplest not-altogether-trivial example of a cumulant expressed as a function of the moments is
$$
\kappa_4(X) = \operatorname E\left( (X-\mu)^4\right) - 3\left( \operatorname E\left((X-\mu)^2\right) \right)^2 \text{ where } \mu = \operatorname E(X).
$$

The $n$th cumulant is homogeneous of degree $n$, i.e. if $c$ is constant (i.e. not random) then $\kappa_n(cX) = c^n \kappa_n(X).$

If $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ are independent then
$$
\kappa_n(X_1+\cdots + X_m) = \kappa_n(X_1)+\cdots + \kappa_n(X_m).
$$

If for $\varnothing \ne I,J \subseteq \{\,1,\ldots,m\,\},$ $I\cap J=\varnothing,$ the tuples $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(X_i)_{i\in J}$ are independent of each other, then $\kappa(X_1,\ldots,X_m) =0 .$

Comment: Indeed, joint moments or, equivalently, joint cumulants can be used to describe dependence of several random variables. The problem here is that that OP wants the generalized covariance $C(X,\dots,X)$ to depend only on the variance of of $X$.